# Why a negative value plus a positive multiple of divisor is congruent to a negative value?Should we think that this is a kind of rule?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$  \left( \text{negative integer} + \text{positive multiple of divisor}  \right)  \equiv \left( \text{negative integer}  \right)  ~\left(\mathrm{mod}\ \left(  \text{divisor}  \right)\right)  $$

Why this congruence can be held?

I done below computations for example.

$$  \left( -1 \right) ~\mathrm{mod5}~  \tag{1}  $$

$$ = \left( -1+5  \right) ~\mathrm{mod5}~  \tag{2}  $$

$$ = \left( 4 \right)~\mathrm{mod5}~ \tag{3}   $$

$$ = 4 $$

$$ \therefore ~~  -1 \equiv 4 ~\left(\mathrm{mod}\ \left( 5  \right)\right)  $$

So I added 5 at tag2 naturally but how is it adequete to do so?

Can I assume that we can add the multiple of 5 to inside the braces of $~ \left( -1 \right)~\mathrm{mod5}~   ~$ without thinking  some any conception(s)(I don't know what are it).

I have no memory why I can  add 5 at tag2 is ok.

Just because it is a rule?

Comment: This is not clear.  When you are working $\pmod n$ there is no notion of sign.  $1\equiv -1\pmod 2$ for example, so what is the sign?  And if you meant remainder, as programmers tend to use the word mod, then there can be no negative.  The remainder is always $≥0$.

Comment: Depending on the context , sometimes the remainder with minimal absolute value is used , but the modulo-operation usually only uses positive integers with a non-negative integer as a result. Do not confuse "$a\mod b = c$" with "$a\equiv c\mod b$". In the latter case, for fixed $a$ and $b$ , infinite many $c$ satisfy the congruence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is actually

$$
\text{any integer $x$} 
\equiv  \text{the same integer $x$}  + \text{any multiple of divisor}
 \pmod{\text{divisor}}.
$$

If the notation $(\text{mod $d$})$ has been defined using any of the standard definitions, this rule is easily derived from the definition.
For example, we might make the definition that

$$  a \equiv b \pmod d $$

if and only if $a - b$ is some integer multiple of $d.$
In that case, let $d = \text{divisor},$
let $a = x$,
let $b = x + \text{multiple of divisor}$,
and let the multiple of the divisor $d$ be $kd$
(so that $k$ is an integer), and we have

$$ a - b = x - (x + kd) = (-k)d, $$

and since $(-k)d$ is an integer multiple of $d$ it follows that
$a \equiv b \pmod d.$

In your case, let $5$ be the divisor, substitute $-1$ for "any integer $x$", and
substitute $5$ for "any multiple of divisor",
and indeed it must be the case that

$$ -1 \equiv -1 + 5 \pmod 5. $$